# Android headless sdk update

Tags: android, sdk, updates

I am trying to update the Android sdk on one of my servers.
As I connect through SSH, I run the android command with -u for a headless install.

The first command I run is ./android list sdk -u -a -e, to get the full list of sdks available.

The one I am trying to install is "build Tools v23", which appears in the list :

```
----------
id: 3 or "build-tools-23.0.0"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23
----------
```

The documentation states that I can install this package using the command
./android update sdk -u -t XXXX
where XXX is the filter, which could be the id "3" or the package name "build-tools-23.0.0".

Updating other packages using their package name worked well, but each time I run the command for this package, I get this error :
    Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.0'

If I try to install the package using its id, the android tool installs another package which has nothing to do with build-tools.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after playing with the command I finally found what I did wrong.

The identifiers returned by the ./android list sdk -u -a -e command can only be used when using the same "-a" parameter on the ./android update sdk -u -t XXX command.
Thus the command to update is ./android update sdk -u -a -t XXX where XXX is my filter.